# Embedded bootstrap div not responsive in un bootstrap sites

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My requirement is to embed a bootstrap style div in few existing sites. Existing sites may have bootstrap or not bootstrap implementations.

Typical html structures below,

```html
<!--Existing site html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <here thier styles and scripts>
</head>
<body>

   <Existing site body>

    <!--My embedded div below-->
   <div class="my-embedded-div">
    <here my bootstrap prefixed style sheet(Ex:[.my-embedded-div allbootstrap styles])>
    <all my divs , modals and components>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Issue below,

- I am inserting my div in existing bootstrap site(existing site has thier own bootstrap version implementations). This scenario my elements inside my embeds div is responsive in all devices.This scenario fine.

  [image]
- But when i implement with un-bootstrap site(Existing site which dont have bootstrap implementstions). My embed div not responsive at all. Like shown below,

  [image]

  Even i have meta *name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0* still its not responsive.

  How i can resolve this case?

**Note:** I just handle conflict bootstrap by adding prefix to my parent element and prefixing my bootstrap plugins(Reference [link](https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap)). I am using bootstrap 4.1.3 , also i am not expert in html designs please.

Comment: I'm not sure If I did understand well your question. If you just want to use bootstrap and make it responsive. Why don't add the CDN component link of bootstrap to the head? check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: There are several requirements for the bootstrap grid system to work properly. With the absolutely generic “example” you have shown, we can’t possibly tell whether those are fulfilled or not. Please provide a proper example, that actually show which BS components you are using, and how/in which context.